# Gitolite and http Error 500. Permission issue in setup

Tags: http, permissions, gitolite

I attempted to install Gitolite on a Fedora 17 server with the aim of setting up git and HTTP access along with authorisation. Git access works OK. Can push and pull. But HTTP access falls over with an Error 500. It appears I got something wrong with permissions.

Here's what I did. I followed instructions from here: `sitaramc.github.com`

I [have documented what I have tried to do here](http://mochapenguin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/setting-up-gitolite-git-and-http-access.html) if anyone would like to see it down to detail.

HTTP Error:

> Internal Server Error - 500
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Error Log - /var/log/httpd/error-git.log

> [Wed Feb 13 08:26:11 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.40] suexec failure: could not open log file
>   [Wed Feb 13 08:26:11 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.40] fopen: Permission denied
>   [Wed Feb 13 08:26:11 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.40] Premature end of script headers: gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh
>   [Wed Feb 13 08:30:13 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.40] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/git/

*** Update 1 ***
 - Managed to post the error output here.

*** Update 2 ***
Relaxed permissions on log directory and gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh. More details are available at the link above where I have documented in detail.
/var/log/httpd/error-git.log

> [Wed Feb 13 21:18:47 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.40] suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
>   [Wed Feb 13 21:18:47 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.40] Premature end of script headers: gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh
>   [Wed Feb 13 21:18:54 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.40] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/git/
>
> $ sudo more /var/log/httpd/suexec.log
>   [2013-02-13 21:18:47]: uid: (990/git) gid: (988/git) cmd: gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh
>   [2013-02-13 21:18:47]: cannot stat program: (gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh)

Not sure where next

*** Update 3 ***

Ok, so I made some progress. I may have fixed the permissions issue. Now facing a PATH issue. Like before, most relevant output is included here. Full details are  updated at the link in my original post.

My knowledge of Apache config is very basic. After reading about suEXEC, I realised the permission issue could be arising out of SELinux. So I disabled it for now. (Would like to identify a way of having gitolite working with SELinux active, but that's for later. Suggestions are welcome.)

Now when I access the url: http:// mochapenguin /git/testing.git in browser

001E# service=git-upload-pack
0000003BERR FATAL: unknown git/gitolite command: 'testing.git'

When I test from the client machine, I see:

> ssh git@mochapenguin \echo $PATH
>   FATAL: unknown git/gitolite command: 'echo /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/mochapenguin/.local/bin:/home/mochapenguin/bin'

*** Update 4 ***
Alright, got it working. No further change was needed since my last update.

I ought to have tried accessing the repo like so, instead of trying the URL in the browser:

```
git clone http://username:password@mochapenguin/git/testing.git
```

This setup allows clone and push over http

I can't figure out what I got wrong.

Could someone point me the right way, please?

Comment: "Permission denied": can you try and set more permissive rights to gitolite directories (where the logs are) and to `sudo chmod 0755 /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh`, just to understand exactly what causes that error message?

Comment: Thanks @VonC Some interesting leads arising out of your suggestion (updates to my original post). I must admit my knowledge on Apache permissions is limited beyond that Apache is initially started by root when it listens to port < 1024. There is root, apache and git permissions in the mix now. I'll Google for suexec policy violations now.

Comment: Ok. For what it's worth, here are my settings for an https Gitolite access through Apache: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L95-L132

Comment: Thanks @VonC I've bookmarked your Apache config. I shall have to refer to it as I improve my config gradually.

Comment: Are you sure, though, that your url you are using doesn't bypass gitolite?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but my understanding of http mode access with gitolite is that Apache Web Server acts as a proxy when using the http url, that is .. Apache authenticates the user and invokes the gitolite wrapper through suEXEC based on the entires in the .ssh/authorized_users file and passes the git command through. It would be nice if there was an easy way to test (??) I can't think of one until a couple of repositories and users have been set up.

Comment: No suexec involved: here are the two main lines when it comes to https access of git repos through gitolite: https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/passenger/apache/env.conf.tpl#L107-L108

Comment: I do have a ScriptAlias set up like so: ScriptAlias /git/ /var/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/ in my Apache config. In my setup gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh invokes gitolite-shell after setting environment variables. The second line in your config sets up one for git-http-backend. Setting up git-http-backend would be next on my list. I followed this guide: http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/ssh-and-http.html